# Oracle Grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I want to be able to do is sum up the time for each "episode" of time the ID is with one group and than get the first episode time for NC to C and C to NC and also the last episode time from NC to C and C to NC In the table below I manually added the `GRP_Time` column. Also I have added the end result table

This is the metric I'm trying to generate systematically.

```
ID    ASSign_ID  GRP      Time            GRP_Time   
11    1788       NC       6             
11    1802       NC       1               7
11    2995       C        7               7
11    5496       NC       11              11
11    6077       C        2 
11    6216       C        2
11    6226       C        4               8  
11    6790       NC       5               5
12    1234       C        6               6
12    2345       NC       1               
12    3456       NC       8               9
12    4567       C       11              11
14    6789       C        2 
14    7890       C        2
14    8900       C        4               8  
14    8904       NC       5               5
```

Result Table

```
ID   First_ET_NC_C    First_ET_C_NC   LAST_ET_NC_C   LAST_ET_C_NC
11   7                7               11             8
12   9                6                9             6 
14   -                8                -             8
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
with seq as 
(    
  select tbl.*, 
      row_number() over(order by assign_id) rn  -- naturalized the order
  from tbl
),
grp as 
(
  select cr.*,          
     sum(case when cr.grp = pr.grp or pr.grp is null then 0 else 1 end)
     over(order by cr.rn) gn      
  from seq cr -- current row
  left join seq pr -- previous row
  on pr.rn = cr.rn - 1
)
,run as
(
  select grp.*,
      sum(time) over(partition by gn order by rn) as run_tot
  from grp
)
select 
   id, assign_id, grp, time,
   case when max(rn) over(partition by gn) <> rn then 
      null
   else
      run_tot
   end as run_total
from run r;
```

Output:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      RUN_TOTAL
11        1788      NC        6         (null)
11        1802      NC        1         7
11        2995      C         7         7
11        5496      NC        11        11
11        6077      C         2         (null)
11        6216      C         2         (null)
11        6226      C         4         8
11        6790      NC        5         5
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faacc/1

---

How it works:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      RN        GN
11        1788      NC        6         1         0
11        1802      NC        1         2         0
11        2995      C         7         3         1
11        5496      NC        11        4         2
11        6077      C         2         5         3
11        6216      C         2         6         3
11        6226      C         4         7         3
11        6790      NC        5         8         4
```

We basically need to assign a group number(`GN` column) to a contiguous grp. Then from that we can do a running total partitioned by GN

You can see the progression of the query here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faacc/1

Each step builds on the top of the previous step. Just scroll down to see how the solution progresses

---

**EDIT**

The query could be shortened, since your report doesn't show the running of total on each row, and it only shows on last row, instead of `sum(time) over(partition by gn order by rn) as run_tot`, we could just do `sum(time) over(partition by gn) as run_tot`, i.e. we remove the `order by rn`; then detect if the row is the last row, if it is then do the `sum over`, otherwise show null.

Final query:

```
with seq as 
(

  select
  
     tbl.*, 
     row_number() over(order by assign_id) rn  -- naturalized the order
  from tbl
),
grp as 
(
  select 
   
     cr.*,
      
     sum(case when cr.grp = pr.grp or pr.grp is null then 0 else 1 end)
     over(order by cr.rn) gn
  
  from seq cr -- current row
  left join seq pr -- previous row
  on pr.rn = cr.rn - 1
)
select
     grp.*,

     case when max(rn) over(partition by gn) <> rn then -- if not last row
        null
     else -- if last row
        sum(time) over(partition by gn) 
     end as running_total
from grp;
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faacc/7

---

---

**EDIT**

Regarding multiple ID, e.g. 6790:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME
11        1788      NC        6
11        1802      NC        1
11        2995      C         7
11        5496      NC        11
11        6077      C         2
11        6216      C         2
11        6226      C         4
11        6790      NC        5
12        6790      NC        1
12        6791      NC        3
12        6792      NC        1
12        6793      NC        4
12        6794      C         1
12        6795      C         6
12        6797      C         8
13        6793      C         1
13        6794      C         4
13        6795      C         3
```

There's two similar ASSIGN_ID, e.g. 6790, yet it belong on a bigger group(on ID, for 11 and 12), so in order to segregate those two group, we must partition them by ID.

Here's the final query, note the **added this** on comments: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83789/2

```
with seq as 
(    
  select tbl.*, 

     -- added this: partition by id
     -- naturalized the order: rn       
     row_number() over(partition by id order by assign_id) rn  
  from tbl
)
,grp as 
(
  select cr.*,        

     -- added this: partition by cr.id
     sum(case when cr.grp = pr.grp then 0 else 1 end)
     over(partition by cr.id order by cr.rn) gn      
  from seq cr -- current row
  left join seq pr -- previous row
  on 
    pr.id = cr.id -- added this
    and pr.rn = cr.rn - 1
)
select id, assign_id, grp, time, 

     -- added this: partition by id
     case when max(rn) over(partition by id,gn) <> rn then 
        null
     else
        -- added this: partition by id
        sum(time) over(partition by id,gn) 
     end as running_total
from grp
order by id, rn;
```

Output:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      RUNNING_TOTAL
11        1788      NC        6         (null)
11        1802      NC        1         7
11        2995      C         7         7
11        5496      NC        11        11
11        6077      C         2         (null)
11        6216      C         2         (null)
11        6226      C         4         8
11        6790      NC        5         5
12        6790      NC        1         (null)
12        6791      NC        3         (null)
12        6792      NC        1         (null)
12        6793      NC        4         9
12        6794      C         1         (null)
12        6795      C         6         (null)
12        6797      C         8         15
13        6793      C         1         (null)
13        6794      C         4         (null)
13        6795      C         3         8
```

How that works, note the **ID and GN**:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      RN        GN        RUNNING_TOTAL
11        1788      NC        6         1         1         (null)
11        1802      NC        1         2         1         7
11        2995      C         7         3         2         7
11        5496      NC        11        4         3         11
11        6077      C         2         5         4         (null)
11        6216      C         2         6         4         (null)
11        6226      C         4         7         4         8
11        6790      NC        5         8         5         5
12        6790      NC        1         1         1         (null)
12        6791      NC        3         2         1         (null)
12        6792      NC        1         3         1         (null)
12        6793      NC        4         4         1         9
12        6794      C         1         5         2         (null)
12        6795      C         6         6         2         (null)
12        6797      C         8         7         2         15
13        6793      C         1         1         1         (null)
13        6794      C         4         2         1         (null)
13        6795      C         3         3         1         8
```

See the query progression here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83789/2

---

**UPDATE** Try to use this one, it's more concise and readable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629498

Comment: I like how showed the breakouts of the different queries, however if you're going the `ROW_NUMBER()` route its probably safe to assume that assign_id is a sequence id but its not guaranteed to be contiguous for a given ID. So I would do `ROW_NUBMER OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY ASSIGN_ID)` instead of `ORDER BY (NULL)`

Comment: Yep, it's only now I noticed that the assign_id is already sequential, I removed the `order by null` already. I thought the OP's data has no available sequential column(I made one and just follow the natural order based on INSERT order, hence the `order by null`), upon realizing assign_id is already sequential, I removed the `order by null` immediately

Comment: Nice +1 btw I'm totally stealing your progression of queries idea

Comment: You flatten first the result of your previous query, and you put it in CTE, you give it an alias, say `tbl` for example. Then that `tbl` will be easier to manage as it provides you a flatter view of your query; then you assign a row_number on that `tbl`, then you put it on another CTE, then you give it an alias, say `seq` (as in sequential); then after that, you can easily join the current row of seq to its previous row

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was able to put in in ym query but now what is happening is since I have multiple ID it suming up everything but I wanted it per ID

Comment: @user1399137 I suspected that might be an issue there's another solution *cough, cough* that takes that into account

Comment: what wpuld be the other solution I am new to the group could you please specify

Comment: what would be the other solution to accomodate multiple Id's I am new to the group could you please specify

Comment: @user1399137 seriously? ok I authored the other answer below that used `LAG` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` . Also btw you might want to check out [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/148672) I would have read your comment earlier.

Comment: @user1399137 I amended the query just now, the data are properly partitioned already

Comment: @conradfrix Thanks now I have a partitioned dataset I wanted to calculate first handoff like first transfer from NC to C and C to NC the grp time in the above example the the Value NC to C is 7 and C to NC is 7 too but this may not always be the case the ID might start with C and handoff to NC or just end there itself would you have any idean how to calculate that ?

Comment: @user1399137 Its not clear to me why mine or Michael's answers aren't  working for you. Perhaps you should edit your question to show the  cases we're missing. Including a SQL Fiddle with the Table Creation and inserts would be nice too!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBuen the new solution works great need one last help on this query  where I want to calculate get first grp time and last group time  for NC to C and C to NC

Comment: @conradfrix below are the column name I want the final result ID, First_NC_to_C, First_C_to_NC, Last_NC_to_C, Last_C_to_NC Also the case may not always begin with NC group it might be start with C group as well Sorry if I am not clear

Comment: @conradfrix Create Table Result_tbl
(ID int, First_ET_NC_C int, First_ET_C_NC int, LAST_ET_NC_C int, LAST_ET_C_NC int )

INSERT ALL
INTO RESULT_TBL (ID, First_ET_NC_C, First_ET_C_NC, LAST_ET_NC_C, LAST_ET_C_NC )
VALUES(11,7,7,11,8)

Comment: @user1399137 You'll get a better response if edit the question, since that way everyone can see it. If you're having trouble editing you can check out the [Editing Faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/148672)

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks I have updated the question Please let me know if it is not clear

Comment: @MichaelBuen I have updated the question Please let me know if there is a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query on Oracle only since it uses LAG()

```
SELECT Table1.ID, 
       Table1.ASSign_ID, 
       Table1.GRP, 
       Table1.TIME, 
       grpSum.GRP_TIME 
FROM   Table1 
       left join (SELECT ID, 
                         MAX(ASSIGN_ID) ASSIGN_ID, 
                         SUM(TIME)      GRP_TIME 
                  FROM   (SELECT ID, 
                                 ASSIGN_ID, 
                                 GRP, 
                                 TIME, 
                                 SUM(GC) over (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY ID, ASSIGN_ID ) g 
                          FROM   (SELECT ID, 
                                         ASSIGN_ID, 
                                         GRP, 
                                         TIME, 
                                         CASE 
                                           WHEN GRP = Lag(GRP) over (ORDER BY ID, ASSIGN_ID) 
                                               THEN  0 
                                               ELSE 1 
                                         END gc 
                                  FROM   TABLE1) a) b
                  GROUP  BY ID, 
                            GRP, 
                            g) grpSum 
         ON table1.ID = grpSum.ID 
            AND table1.ASSIGN_ID = grpSum.ASSIGN_ID 
ORDER BY Table1.ID, 
         Table1.ASSign_ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49de7/10)

Gaps and Islands solutions are a little difficult to describe but here's what each part does

- The inner most query "A" uses LAG to assign a 1 to first item in a
  "episode" and then 0 for every member aftwards.
- The next query "B" uses SUM OVER to assign each member of a "episode" the same
  identifier. Note the same identifier will be used for different episode if the GRP is different
- The query grpSum just does a sum  for the time for each "episode" and Identifies the
  largest Assing_ID as the last time in the "episode"
- Then we left join the original table on the ID and do the projection.

*I'm stealing Michael's progression demonstration idea*

You can see the progression of the [subqueries here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49de7/17)  (scroll down)

Note: you can use also use the `CASE MAX OVER` and `SUM OVER` technique from Micheal's answer to remove the LEFT JOIN and grpSUM query

```
SELECT ID, 
       ASSIGN_ID, 
       GRP, 
       TIME, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Max(ASSIGN_ID) OVER (partition BY ID, GRP, G) = ASSIGN_ID THEN 
         SUM (TIME) OVER (partition BY ID, GRP, G) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END GRP_TIME 
FROM   (SELECT ID, 
               ASSIGN_ID, 
               GRP, 
               TIME, 
               Sum(GC) OVER (partition BY GRP ORDER BY ID, ASSIGN_ID ) g 
        FROM   (SELECT ID, 
                       ASSIGN_ID, 
                       GRP, 
                       TIME, 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN GRP = Lag(GRP) OVER (ORDER BY ID, ASSIGN_ID) THEN 
                         0 
                         ELSE 1 
                       END gc 
                FROM   TABLE1) a) b
    ORDER BY ID, 
             ASSign_ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49de7/35)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so bent on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624010) to use row_number, on my presumption that there's no good candidate for sorting rows(in fact I do an `ORDER BY NULL` at first code iteration, to make it explicit that the code rely on physical ordering of the rows).  I should have started from the clean slate already when I noticed that there's a natural order on your data.

The id + assign_id is a natural fit for partitioning rows and ordering, we could formulate a simpler query then, we could just use LAG.

This is the shortest and simplest query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6c14/3

```
with hm as -- headers marked
(
    select tbl.*,

      case when lag(grp) over(partition by id order by assign_id) = grp then 
        0 
      else 
        1 
      end mark_header

    from tbl
)
,grp as -- grouping
(
    select 
      hm.*,

      -- gn: group number
      sum(mark_header) over(partition by id order by assign_id) as gn
    from hm
)
select -- final query
    id, assign_id, grp, time,

    case when max(assign_id) over(partition by id,gn) = assign_id then
       sum(time) over(partition by id,gn) 
    else
       null
    end as running_total
from grp
order by id, assign_id;
```

Output:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      RUNNING_TOTAL
11        1788      NC        6         (null)
11        1802      NC        1         7
11        2995      C         7         7
11        5496      NC        11        11
11        6077      C         2         (null)
11        6216      C         2         (null)
11        6226      C         4         8
11        6790      NC        5         5
12        6790      NC        1         (null)
12        6791      NC        3         (null)
12        6792      NC        1         (null)
12        6793      NC        4         9
12        6794      C         1         (null)
12        6795      C         6         (null)
12        6797      C         8         15
13        6793      C         1         (null)
13        6794      C         4         (null)
13        6795      C         3         8
```

How that works, note the **ID and GN**, that's where we build upon our running total:

```
ID        ASSIGN_ID GRP       TIME      MARK_HEADER  GN
11        1788      NC        6         1            1
11        1802      NC        1         0            1
11        2995      C         7         1            2
11        5496      NC        11        1            3
11        6077      C         2         1            4
11        6216      C         2         0            4
11        6226      C         4         0            4
11        6790      NC        5         1            5
12        6790      NC        1         1            1
12        6791      NC        3         0            1
12        6792      NC        1         0            1
12        6793      NC        4         0            1
12        6794      C         1         1            2
12        6795      C         6         0            2
12        6797      C         8         0            2
13        6793      C         1         1            1
13        6794      C         4         0            1
13        6795      C         3         0            1
```

See the progression here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6c14/3

---

***Could*** be Oracle-optimized (use DECODE instead of CASE WHEN): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6c14/6

```
with hm as -- headers marked
(
    select tbl.*,

      decode(lag(grp) over(partition by id order by assign_id), grp, 0, 1)
         as mark_header

    from tbl
)
,grp as -- grouping
(
    select 
      hm.*,

      sum(mark_header) over(partition by id order by assign_id) as gn
    from hm
)
select -- final query
    id, assign_id, grp, time,

    decode(max(assign_id) over(partition by id,gn), assign_id,           
       sum(time) over(partition by id,gn), null) as running_total 

from grp
order by id, assign_id;
```